# Google api php client returns eventually null, but with no errors or warnings

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to follow this Google Analytics tutorial:

http://blog.anorgan.com/2015/01/15/using-google-analytics-api-with-php/

I'm not sure if this is good for my needs, but I wanted to do **something** at the end of the day. At least as a training.

I ended up with this code:

```
$items = $data->getRows();  
var_dump($items);
```

Showing `null`. But there is data in GA. There are no errors, no warnings. And I do have them enabled:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

What's more not funny, when I intentionally make mistakes in "OAuth2 service account ClientId" or "OAuth2 service account email address" there are no errors/warnings as well.

The library (I mean Google api php client) uses exceptions extensively (70 occurrences). But nothing is thrown (unless when I make a typo in "OAuth2 service account p12 key file", so exceptions generally do work).

Then how can I know what's happening and where the problem is?

p.s. What I want to accomplish is that I want to create a service which, after a client gives us his Google Analytics credentials (I don't what this can be yet), we will gather some statistical data from his/her analytics account and then will send this data to client's email, after doing some calculations.

**Update:** 
here is my code:

```
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  require_once 'google_api_client/src/Google/autoload.php';
  // OAuth2 service account p12 key file
  $p12FilePath = 'analytics-c70e9f12f1e1.p12';

  // OAuth2 service account ClientId
  $serviceClientId = 'xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  // OAuth2 service account email address
  $serviceAccountName = 'peak-geode-xyz@appspot.gserviceaccount.com';

  // Scopes we're going to use, only analytics for this tutorial
  $scopes = array(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
  );

  $googleAssertionCredentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
          $serviceAccountName, $scopes, file_get_contents($p12FilePath)
  );

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($googleAssertionCredentials);
  $client->setClientId($serviceClientId);
  $client->setApplicationName("Analytics");    

  // Create Google Service Analytics object with our preconfigured Google_Client
  $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

  // Add Analytics View ID, prefixed with "ga:"
  $analyticsViewId    = 'ga:xyz';//

  $startDate          = '2016-01-27';
  $endDate            = '2016-02-25';
  $metrics            = 'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews';

  $data = $analytics->data_ga->get($analyticsViewId, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, array(
      'dimensions'    => 'ga:pagePath',
      'filters'       => 'ga:pagePath==http://konradpapala.beep.pl/',
      'sort'          => '-ga:pageviews',
  ));

  // Data 
  $items = $data->getRows();  
  var_dump($items);//gives null
```

Comment: Did you consider that you have no data for that request?

Comment: @DaImTo thanks. Yes I did so I checked twice. What I want is `$metrics            = 'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews';` between 2015-10-01 and 2016-02-25 and yes, when I enter https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/ then I see sessions and pageviews in this time period.

Comment: And you granted the service account access to your Google Analytics data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I followed another tutorial, and on this page: https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts?project=xyz (through Analytic API -> credentials -> manage services), I copied email address of my service and then followed this tutorial: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en (Add users part) to give this user permissions. Is it this?

Comment: @DaImTo ^ I forgot to call you.

Comment: Take the service account email address. Go the Google analytics website.  In the admin section at the account level add it as a user.  It only needs read access but it must be at the account level.   It should be giving you an error if you don't have access to it though.

Comment: Yes, I did this. Doesn't help. And yes, as far as I remember, there was an error. Now there is no error. No nothing.

Comment: Try and run it here to make sure there is data https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: @DaImTo yes, there is data.

Comment: @DaImTo as I said, there is data in query-explorer. Btw. I have to leave my office now, I hope you'll be here on Monday :) I'll then add my code and ask a few questions, if you don't mind. Thanks for your hitherto (I've just learned a new word:) ) help!

Comment: @DaImTo I added my source code. Can you please look at it?

Comment: I finally managed to do what I, but with a different library: https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP/graphs/contributors I could not get Google official API client to work.